# MapView in fragment error

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I get an android.inflate.Exception when inflate this .xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="***"
    />
```

This class inflate the .xml (fragment_b.xml)

```
public class BFragment extends Fragment {

private MapView mMapView;
private GoogleMap googleMap;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // inflat and return the layout
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);
    mMapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.map);
    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mMapView.onResume();//needed to get the map to display immediately

    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    googleMap = mMapView.getMap();

    return v;
}
```

}

I have try a lot of thing with the .xml without results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aren't you mixing `map api V1` and `map api V2` implementations?

**This is map v1:**

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="***"
/>
```

**This is how map api V2 would look like:**

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Since in your XML you have created an instance of map_v1, you are not allowed to invoke `onCreate()` and `onResume()` - you have to do that for `map_v2` though.

Also you should remember that in `map_v2` you must call `onCreate()`, `onResume()` **only** when appropriate event happens in your activity/fragment lifecycle... So you must call those only from your activity/fragment `onCreate` and `onResume`